# sysinternals commnad psfile hangs when using a local admin account from task scheduler

Tags: sysinternals

I can execute my batch from an administrative command window using my own id but trying to run it using a local admin account or another network account that's in the administrators group of the server and psfile hangs.

So I'm wondering if there is a local or group policy I could set that would allow me to use the other accounts.

The files I'm closing are local to the server I'm running the batch file from so I'm hoping to be able to use the local admin account.

If you are interested, here is my code:

```
    echo Starting CloseFiles %date% %time%
    FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,60) DO (
        echo Iteration %%i
        echo Closing all files in pub_LocatorsAGOL
        C:\SysInternalsSuite\psfile E:\ArcGISServer\Site\pub_LocatorsAGOL -c <NUL >> PSFileAGOL.log 2>&1
        echo Closing all files in pub_LocatorsLL
        C:\SysInternalsSuite\psfile E:\ArcGISServer\Site\pub_LocatorsLL -c <NUL >> PSFilesLL.log 2>&1
        echo Waiting a minute before repeating again
        timeout /T 5
    )
    echo Close Files has finished at %time%
```